# Java concept inheritance hack?

Tags: java

This is a mistake?

The problem : I have 4 classes `V`, `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`.

The class `E` need to extend `V`, `A`, `B`, `D`, but how?

```
Class A extends V{}
Class B extends A{} // this class extends A and V
Class D extends B{} // this class extends A , V and B

Class E extends D{} // Multiples
```

This is possible, but is it correct? I know that Java has no multiple inheritance.

Comment: Yes, `E` does extend all of those classes; but can I suggest that you have a design problem if you need `E` to extend them all.

Comment: Each class only inherits from one parent. Just because they too have their own parent doesn't affect this.

Comment: What you are describing is not multiple inheritance and is perfectly correct. Multiple inheritance is when a class extends mutliple other, usually unrelated, and often incompatible classes.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, `E` is a child of `D` and *transitively* also a descendant of `B`, `A` and `v`. This is perfectly legal and supported in Java. But this is *not* multiple inheritance.

The fact that Java doesn't support multiple inheritance for classes is about a different situation: you cannot *directly* extend multiple classes, e.g. the following is *not* supported in Java: `class E extends D, B`, or `class Child extends ParentA, ParentB`.

Java allows *implementing multiple interfaces* though, and allows multiple inheritance for interfaces, i.e. the following would be allowed:

```
 interface ParentA ...

 interface ParentB ...

 interface Child extends ParentA, ParentB ...
```

Answer (score 0):

`E` Does indeed extend `V`,`A`, `B`, `D`, given your code sample.

I'm not sure the point of your question, are you implying that you would prefer it not be a long-chain of inheritance?

You could consider implementing `V`,`A`, `B`, `D` as interfaces.
Then you could do:

`class E implements V, A, B, D`